# How to make label and value inline in action layout?

Tags: page-layout, action

I am using an action layout to display fields here. But I am unable to make fields and its values inline. Can someone help me out?
[image]

Comment: I don't think there is a way without writing a custom LWC to achieve this

Comment: This stacked layout is adopted to make the form as adaptable to narrow devices as possible without truncating values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option called display density in the User interface setting. I changed it to compact and it is working fine now.
[image]